# Ubuntu, can not start react-native: Could not find tools.jar

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

I followed the [getting started guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) Android/Linux.

I try to start react native under ubuntu using `react-native run-android`, but it fails with the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not find tools.jar
```

How can I fix it?

Full output:

```
 $ react-native run-android
    Starting JS server...
    /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
    Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0361Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
    :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Could not find tools.jar
```

Running `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Solved it by installing openjdk again:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: Thanks @abimelex. I got same issue now resolved by when got installation

Comment: thanks a lot, if android studio currently not running, this helps a lot

Answer (score 13):

In Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: The culprit!]

Check to make sure the Java compiler is available.  I don't normally develop in Java, so, while there's Java stuff running, I haven't ever specifically compiled a Java project.  Run:

```
javac -version
```

If you get the same thing I received, well... you know the issue.  I installed the latest Oracle JDK (*shiver*), and I have react-native up and running now.  I ran into some other issues with environment variables, which were solved by:

```
unset $JAVA_HOME
source ~/.profile
```

Note: the .profile script had my SDK env vars in it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice! I've installed openjdk, however, I was missing the -devel package on my openSuse Leap 15.1 distro.

Answer (score 3):

If you came here from google and you are developing on RHEL you need

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc
```

and

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem as well..... after installing openjdk using the synaptic package

```
npx react-native run-android
```

couldn't able to install the app in the device bring the same. Not until i installed openjdk-8-jdk in terminal like this...

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 2):

got this error after knowing i only installed the openjdk-8-**jre**-headless instead of openjdk-8-**jdk**-headless. note the subtle difference between **jre** vs **jdk**